# How to update dsp:droplet with ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, ajax, atg

I have a `scheduler` that updates value every 10 seconds. This `scheduler` is used inside a `droplet`. This droplet is used on a `jsp` page

```
<dsp:droplet name="/path/to/droplet/Droplet">
    <dsp:oparam name="output">
        <dsp:valueof param="myParamName"/>
    </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

Also there's a `dsp:input`, that calls to javascript function whenever it's pressed. `Droplet` shows correct values before input is pressed and after, but in order to show new value, I have to reload the page.

My question is - how to update `droplet` value with ajax, without reloading the page?

Comment: Poorly asked question which is very vague. A scheduler should not be inside a droplet.  A scheduler should update a value outside of the droplet.  You can probably use the jquery setTimeout() to call the droplet which you will need to expose as a web service.

Comment: Scheduler updates a value outside of the droplet. In droplet I just get an updated value from scheduler

Comment: So then wrap a web service around the droplet and call the web service every 10 seconds using jquery setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

Write an Ajax call which calls a jsp which contains the droplet call, as:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/newPage.jsp',
    ...
```

});

and in newPage.jsp put:

```
<dsp:droplet name="/path/to/droplet/Droplet">
    <dsp:oparam name="output">
    <dsp:valueof param="myParamName"/>
   </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

Then schedule Ajax call when you want